# symfony2 factory-service in yaml

Tags: symfony, sylius

Looking at the code of the Sylius Bundle for Symfony I noticed the Resource Bundle has an interesting way of defining resource controllers as services.
Here is the cart item controller service configuration in XML

```
<service id="sylius.controller.cart_item" class="%sylius.controller.cart_item.class%">
        <argument type="service">
            <service factory-service="sylius.controller.configuration_factory" factory-method="createConfiguration" class="Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\Configuration">
                <argument>sylius</argument>
                <argument>cart_item</argument>
                <argument>SyliusCartBundle:CartItem</argument>
            </service>
        </argument>
        <call method="setContainer">
            <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        </call>
    </service>
```

If I understand it correctly this code instantiates the controller class and passes as the constructor argument the result of a call to the factory-method "createConfiguration" in the factory-service class. Arguments are specified, so everything is fine.

My question is twofold:
1) Where is this documented? I could not find one example of this kind of arguments-as-a factory-callable in the docs.
2) What would be the YAML version of this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the way:

```
<service id="sylius.controller.cart_item" class="%sylius.controller.cart_item.class%">
    <argument type="service">
        <service factory-service="sylius.controller.configuration_factory" factory-method="createConfiguration" class="Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\Configuration">
            <argument>sylius</argument>
            <argument>cart_item</argument>
            <argument>SyliusCartBundle:CartItem</argument>
        </service>
    </argument>
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
    </call>
</service>
```

Can be written as the following in yml

```
sylius.controller.cart_item:
    class: %sylius.controller.cart_item.class%
    arguments:
        - "@=service('sylius.controller.configuration_factory').createConfiguration('sylius', 'cart_item', 'SyliusCartBundle:CartItem')"
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer to both of your questions in the [dependency injection docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html).

As far as defining a service nested under another service in YAML, it doesn't seem the parser that ships with Symfony can handle that, but I did find someone's pet project that seems to aim for this functionality: https://gist.github.com/Mikulas/8004470

Comment: Honestly the dependency injection docs is the first place I looked at. In the page you linked there is an example of using a factory to create a service. I was looking for an example of using a factory to create a service that is passed as an argument to a different service, which is just slightly different. That is what the xml above does. Its similar but not the same thing, in my opinion.

Comment: The only difference is syntax. I really don't like the way the Sylius bundle does it here, since the factory service is not reusable. Even if you are 100% sure that your factory service will only be used in one place, declaring it independently still makes more sense from a readability standpoint.

Comment: I agree with you on this. The fact I am asking does not mean that I like it or would suggest using it. :) Still I'd like to know if this syntax is documented anywhere and what the corresponding yml would be... :D

Comment: Ok, just intellectual curiosity then. I can understand that :)

It doesn't seem the default YAML parser can understand nested service definitions, but I did find this [https://gist.github.com/Mikulas/8004470](https://gist.github.com/Mikulas/8004470)

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to override the CartItemController and came across this, because I thought i needed to do it this way. But it's **not** the way to go. Anyways, to answer your question. Here is how the xml transforms into yaml

(because the solution suggested by Alexei Tenitski didn't work for me, I did it like so)

```
sylius.controller.cart_item:
    class:    Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController
    arguments:   ["@sylius.cart_item.config_factory"]
    calls:
       - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]

sylius.cart_item.config_factory:
    class:  Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\Configuration
    factory_class: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ConfigurationFactory
    factory_method: createConfiguration
    arguments: ["sylius", "cart_item", "SyliusCartBundle:CartItem"]
```

But I'm guessing you were trying to override the CartItem controller, right? :) that's what I was trying to do anyways.

In the [Sylius Docs](http://sylius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bundles/general/overriding_controllers.html) is explained how you would go about doing that. Like this :

```
location : yourbundle/resources/config/config.yml

sylius_cart:
    classes:
        item:
            controller: YourBundle\Controller\CartItemController
```

Also, make sure that if you configure the route to your new controller action, you use the controller service instead of the normal approach.

```
location : yourbundle/resources/config/routing.yml

mybundle_ajaxcart_add:
    path:     /ajax/cart/add
    defaults: { _controller: sylius.controller.cart_item:addAjaxAction }
```

I wanted to post it here, because I was looking for this for about half a day and probably someone is going to be looking for the same solution. And I like to save that person the headache ;)

Comment: Thank you for this info... its very useful for working with Sylius and I am sure it will save many headaches :D. As for me I was interested in using factories in service definitions in yml.